# Adding float values in php

Tags: php, math, addition

Given the following table:

```
type   |  valueOfType


food   |  4.3 

food   |  5.3

dairy  |  3.2

food   |  1.3

food   |  6.7

==============
```

My query needs to search for all "food" type and add all the "valueOfType" where valueOfType is a float type. How can I do it?

edit:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(valueOfType) AS Total FROM productTbl WHERE type ='$post_type' ";
$result = mysql_query($query2) 
or die("Unable to execute query because : " .     mysql_error());

echo $result;
```

Comment: Did you try writing DB query and code afterwards?

Comment: use SUM() function as said by judda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(valueOfType) AS Total FROM foo WHERE type='food'
```

Comment: how do I retrieve the answer of the query? Sorry Im very new at PHP.

I did exactly, but when I echo-ed the answer, it gave me Resource id #3.

Comment: Using the `mysql_query` or whatever functions you are using to pull information from your database. Tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/

Comment: hi, sorry to bother you again, can you look at the edited question? I've added the coding. Sorry!

Comment: Did you read the tutorial link that I posted?  You need to get the data into an array before emitting it.  `$foo = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); echo $foo['Total'];`

Comment: Oh crap, I didn't notice the tutorial part. Sorry, and thanks for the tip!